# Modular arithmetic to prove recurring sequence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

Say there are points on an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and we want to express these points as $P=kQ$ for an integer $k$ and $P,Q$ are points on the curve.

I notice after $k=10$ that $P$ repeats itself. For example, when k=1 and k=11, we get the same P. This means that when $k=10$ then $Q$ is the point at infinity.

Each new point $P$ for $k>10$ can be represented as the point associated with $k \pmod{10}$.

How can I use modular arithmetic to prove this repeating pattern? Should it be a proof by induction?

Comment: which form of elliptic curve ?

Comment: I edited the question: $y^2=x^3+ax+b$

Comment: We still do not have a well defined question, the values for $a,b,p$ are not known, and in this generality it is hard to pick always a point $Q$ of order ten. If $Q$ has order ten, then there is a canonical map from $\Bbb Z/10$ (abelian group with generator $1$ modulo ten) to $E(\Bbb F_p)$ (rational points of the curve $E$ over the field with $p$ elements $\Bbb F_p$), which maps $1\to Q$ and in general $k$ to $kQ$.